# Startup and shutdown of Application

Tags: c++builder

A typical application looks like this:

```
Application->Initialize();
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1);
Application->Run();
```

After `Run()` what happens from what I could see, it waits to handle all message loop events and after that `Running` property is set to `false`. However, form is not yet destroyed until the very program end.

After comment by David Heffernan I've revised the question:

How can I ensure that the forms have been destroyed after `Run()` or how can I destroy a form which has been created by `CreateForm`? Is there a `DestroyForm()` or similar equivalent?

Comment: The answer to both your question is no. Events can fire after Run returns. And threads may still be running. You might have started them and not stopped them. If you want to destroy the forms, do so. As it stands, they will be destroyed by the finalisation code. But if you want to destroy them sooner, do so. You should ask a question about your problem rather than about your solution.

Comment: Thanks. I have revised the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I ensure that the forms have been destroyed after Run()

The VCL ensures that for you.  `CreateForm()` sets the `Application` as the form's Owner.  When the `Application` object is freed by the VCL's cleanup logic after `WinMain()` exits, it will free everything it owns.

> how can I destroy a form which has been created by CreateForm?

If you want to free it manually, you can simply `delete` it:

```
delete Form1;
```

The form will remove itself from its Owner so it is not freed a second time.

> Is there a DestroyForm() or similar equivalent?

No, nor is one needed.  Simply `delete` it as if you had created it with `new` instead of `CreateForm()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't seem to work. It crashes after `delete Form1;` This is in `Project1.cpp` file after the `catch(...)` (also tried before catch(), same thing). CodeGuard reports "Bad parameter in process". Also, the destructor is not called until the very end of the program as if I didn't delete anything.

Comment: I assure you, it does work. You might need to manually `#include` the Form's .h file to the projct's main .cpp file, as it is not included by default. That will help the compiler know about the Form's class so the `delete` can produce the correct machine code.

Comment: @remy Read the original question, before the edit. Asker is concerned about when form is destroyed. Was hoping that would happen as soon as `Run()` returns.

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't work yesterday but now it works. `delete Form1` deletes right after `Run()` returns and destructor is called. Perhaps I forgot to include `Unit1.h` file in `Project.cpp`. Thank you both for your excellent answers! Too bad I cannot mark both answers as correct because you both deserve points but Remy was just a small bit more precise (but only a small bit).

Comment: Is it safe to do `delete Form1;` if the Form had a TTimer on it? Even if you stop the timer and then `delete`, is there a possibility that the timer may already have posted its message?

Comment: Yes, it is safe. And yes, there is a possibility that the `WM_TIMER` message could have already been posted to the message queue. But, the message loop is no longer running once `Run()` exits, and even if it were still running, by the time the `WM_TIMER` message is pulled from the message queue and dispatched, the timer's `HWND` would be gone so the message would get silently ignored.

Comment: Timer messages are synthesised so that last comment is a little inaccurate.

Comment: I have seen `WM_TIMER` messages get synthesized and dispatched after the owning timer is killed. So they may be synthetic messages, but there does seem to be a race condition surrounding their generation.

Answer (score 2):

Your form is not explicitly destroyed. And so its lifetime is determined by its owner. When its owner is destroyed, it is destroyed. The owner is `Application` which is destroyed in the VCL unit finalization stage. And so your form is destroyed then too.

You wish to know how to destroy a form before it is automatically destroyed by its owner. That is simple: just destroy it when you require it to be destroyed.

```
Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1);
Application->Run();
delete Form1;
```